# How to include doctrine entity manager to files generated by View?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I use mini php MVC. Variables from `bootstrap` are not included in generated `view`. I can include `entityManager` to `index.php`,
but i am not able to include `entityManager` to view files. WHy? How to include doctrine entity manager to files generated by View?

How to include entity manager to `_register1Db.php` file below?
The view is displayed properly, it does not show errors that bootstrap.php is not found (if i chaneg path, such an error is displayed), but view does not include entity manager from bootstrap.php

//1. \src\bootstrap.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$isDevMode = true;
$entitiesPaths = array(__DIR__.'/CrmBundle/Entity');

$dbParams = array(
  'dbname' => 'dbname',
  'user' => 'user',
  'password' => 'pswd',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
);   // 'pdo_mysql',


$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entitiesPaths, $isDevMode);
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

$some='some';
```

//2. \public\index.php

```
require_once '../src/bootstrap.php'; //which requires autoload.php
print_r('<br><br> index some='.$some); // works
var_dump($em);  //works
use core\App;
$app = new App(); //App from urk identifines controller and action and pass url paramteters to them, controller action analize parameters and displays views, in this case  security\register
```

//3. src\CrmBundle\Resources\views\security\register.php

```
include ('_register1Db.php');
```

//4. src\CrmBundle\Resources\views\security_register1Db.php

```
require_once '/../../../../bootstrap.php';  // 
var_dump($em);  // Undefined variable: em 
print_r('<br><br> register some='.$some); //Undefined variable: some
```

//The way i generate the view: src\core\View.php

```
ob_start();
include_once( __DIR__.'/../bootstrap.php' );
include_once( $this->viewTemplatePath.$this->file );
ob_end_flush();
```

// view generation with debugging variables from bootstrap.php :  src\core\View.php

```
    include_once( __DIR__.'/../bootstrap.php' );
    ob_start();
    // think how to render extract variable in order to pass to the file
    include_once( __DIR__.'/../bootstrap.php' );  
    var_dump($em);  //undefined
    print_r('<br><br> parseViewPhpinside some=' . $some); //undefined
    print_r('<br><br> parseViewPhpinside __DIR__=' . __DIR__);  // ....apache2\htdocs\own\log\src\core 
    include_once( $this->viewTemplPath.$this->file );
    if($store) return ob_get_clean(); 
    else ob_end_flush();
    var_dump($em);  //undefined
    print_r('<br><br> parseViewPhp some='.$some);  //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a solution to make things working, but not the answer.

The solution was to create a file `dbcon.php` and include it in `register.php` or `register1Db.php` .

// contents of `dbcon.php`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$isDevMode = true;
$entitiesPaths = array(__DIR__.'/CrmBundle/Entity');
$dbParams = array(
  'dbname' => 'dbname',
  'user' => 'user',
  'password' => 'pswd',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
);   // 'pdo_mysql',
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entitiesPaths, $isDevMode);
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

print_r('<br><br> end of dbcon.php ');
```

I do not understand why does not work if i include bootsrap.php?
But it works if i include similar contents from another file.

Maybe because i already included it once in index.php, which creates object App.php, which displays view files, whereas said view files does not include bootsrap the second time, because it looks that bootstrap is already included, although variables are not available?

What could be the reason?

Comment: How include bootstrap.php in Controllers? event you include it you can not use `$em` on each controller ( for example `index() ` ) now ..how you correct this?

Comment: How we access `$_SESSION` on Controlers?